# What does elimination without row exchanges say about the last row of an upper triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

**This question was taken from MIT OCW and *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Gilbert Strang**

Suppose elimination takes $A$ to $U$ without row exchanges. Then row $j$ of $U$ is a combination of which rows of $A$? If $Ax = 0$, is $Ux = 0$? If $Ax = b$, is $Ux = b$? If $A$ starts out lower triangular, what is the upper triangular $U$?

I have the answer to this question, but I really want to understand what is being asked here and how to arrive at that answer. Any insight that will lead me to understanding this is appreciated.

Comment: What can the last rows of a matrix in echelon form look like?

Comment: The last row will only have a non zero coefficient that is all the way to the right of the matrix.